# How to chamfer only two corners (rectangle) in Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have a rectangular matter.js body and I only want to chamfer the top-left and top-right corners, but not the bottom.  How will I do that?

`Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h, { chamfer: 5 }) // chamfers all corners :(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Bodies.rectangle` calls `Vertices.chamfer` as found on these [lines of code](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/e49834d1e0574348cea3edd4a06d60edf1a67fa0/src/factory/Bodies.js#L47-L48), and it expects that the `chamfer` property be an object. However, if you pass a single number it will apply the same chamfer number to all of the vertices as seen [here](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/f1ba9b583ba92a56d307d63c850a0330d26bbd5e/src/geometry/Vertices.js#L284-L289).

Reading over the [documentation](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Vertices.html#method_chamfer), we found that:

> The radius parameter is a single number or an array to specify the radius for each vertex.

For a rectangle, the vertices are clockwise starting from the top left. After all, to chamfer only the top left and top right corners, the code should be:

```js
Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h, { 
  chamfer: {
    radius: [5,5,0,0]
  }
})
```